# What is the anticommutator of the interior product and codifferential (adjoint of exterior derivative)?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, exterior-algebra

What is $\eta=i_X \delta + \delta i_X$ acting on differential forms? Here $\delta$ is the usual Hodge adjoint of the exterior derivative and $i_X$ is contraction of a form with the vector field $X$. Clearly $\eta=0$ trivially on 0-forms and 1-forms, but does this hold for forms of arbitrary degree?

Comment: I think you mean "adjoint" rather than "Hodge dual" in the second sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Clifford algebra might make this manipulation easier: its geometric product of vectors (or forms) is associative like the wedge product, but still has the metrical terms needed for the codifferential.

In clifford notation, we have,

$$\eta(\alpha) = X \rfloor (\nabla \rfloor \alpha) + \nabla \rfloor (X \rfloor \alpha)$$

You can see here that the contraction operator $\rfloor$ plays a similar role in relating $\nabla \rfloor$ to $\delta$ as it does in relating $X \rfloor$ to $i_X$.

Now we can use associativity of the geometric product to our advantage, considering the grade $k-2$ terms of a general product:

$$\langle \nabla (X \alpha) \rangle_{k-2} = (\nabla \wedge X) \rfloor \alpha - (X \wedge \nabla) \rfloor \alpha = \nabla \rfloor (X \rfloor \alpha)$$

Expand the $(X \wedge \nabla) \rfloor \alpha$ term as

$$\langle X \nabla \alpha \rangle_{k-2} = (X \wedge \nabla) \rfloor \alpha = X\rfloor (\nabla \rfloor \alpha)$$

So we can conclude that the anticommutator is

$$\eta(\alpha) = (\nabla \wedge X) \rfloor \alpha$$

Hm, I'm not familiar with how this should be denoted in pure differential forms.  $\nabla \wedge X$ ought to be something like $dX$, but since $X$ isn't a form (it's a vector field), that's a little weird.  Similarly, $(\nabla \wedge X) \rfloor \alpha$ ought to read like an interior product into $\alpha$, but with 2-vector (or a 2-form, or a mixed 1-vector/1-form) into $\alpha$.

Comment: I don't know much geometric algebra and so struggle to see how this argument makes sense. Even if $\nabla \wedge X$ is to be viewed as a 1-form and $\alpha$ as a $k$-form how is $\nabla \wedge X \rfloor \alpha$ supposed to be a $(k-2)$-form?

Comment: $\nabla \wedge X$ is grade-2.

Comment: $\delta$ is metric-dependent, so it shouldn't be expected that $\eta$ could be expressed with $d$ and $\iota$, which are metric-independent.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily verify that
$$\nabla_Y \iota_X \omega = \iota_X \nabla_Y \omega + \iota_{\nabla_YX} \omega$$
for vector fields $X$ and $Y$. For the codifferential, we have the formula
$$\delta = - \sum_{j=1}^n \iota_{e_j} \nabla_{e_j} \omega$$
which holds for any orthonormal frame $e_1, \dots, e_n$. Hence
$$\delta \iota_X \omega = - \sum_{j=1}^n \iota_{e_j} \nabla_{e_j}\iota_X \omega = - \sum_{j=1}^n \iota_{e_i}\bigl(\iota_X \nabla_{e_i}\omega + \iota_{\nabla_{e_i}X} \omega \bigr) = \sum_{j=1}^n \iota_X \iota_{e_i} \nabla_{e_i}\omega - \sum_{j=1}^n\iota_{e_i}\iota_{\nabla_{e_i}X} \omega$$
where we used that $\iota_X \iota_Y = -\iota_Y \iota_X$ for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$. This can be written as
$$\delta \iota_X \omega + \iota_X \delta \omega = -\iota_{\nabla \wedge X} \omega$$
where
$$\nabla \wedge X := e_i \wedge \nabla_{e_i} X$$
is an anti-symmetric bi-vector.